# Access Kitematic (docker) apache website over port 80

Tags: networking, docker, portforwarding, kitematic

Using Kitematic I have created an Apache webserver and am able to access it over port 32769.

**Port 32769 works** for these scenarios:

- 192.168.99.100 (VirtualBox VM)
- 192.168.1.102 (home network.  Configured VM to forward Host 192.168.1.102 32769 to Guest (no ip) 32769)
- 12.34.56.78 (public IP.  Configured router to forward 32769 to 192.168.1.102)

**Port 80 works** for these scenarios:

- 192.168.99.100 (Virtualbox VM, container port 80)

**Port 80 does not work** for these scenarios:

- 192.168.1.102 (home network, container port 80. Configured VM to forward Host 192.168.1.102 80 to Guest (no ip) 80)
- 12.34.56.78 (public IP, container port 80.  Configured router to forward 80 to 192.168.1.102)
- 192.168.1.102 (home network, container port 32769.  Configured VM to forward Host 192.168.1.102 32769 to Guest (no ip) 80)
- 192.168.1.102 (home network, container port 80.  Configured VM to forward Host 192.168.1.102 80 to Guest (no ip) 32769)

What modifications would allow access to port 80?